# How to install ubuntu and windows XP in same computer?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp

I have hot question that how to install two OS in one computer?

Is it possible to install ubuntu and windows XP?

If yes then how?

Kindly tell me Thanks :)

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? Please thoroughly search for an answer before posting, and see [ask] for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A nice tutorial here](http://apcmag.com/how_to_dual_boot_windows_xp_and_linux_xp_installed_first.htm)

It's called dual boot, meaning you will have to choose between XP and ubuntu every startup.